# Shared App Group Container Is Not Sharing Between Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, cocoa-touch, today-extension

**Expected behaviour:**
All devices will share the same `core data` `sqlite` file using a shared directory in `containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier` rather than documents folder using a today extension

**Whats actually happening:**
Device 1 loads sqlite file into the group container.  On reload app checks if its there, if it is fine, if not add it. Device 1 **is** finding shared container `sqlite` so is working as expected. **However**, add another device (device 2) and it cant find the `sqlite` file and adds its own.  So now its just like a remote documents directory, but not common to other devices which is what is required.

**Points to note:**

- Both app target and today extension share the same group id.
- App is writing the sqlite file to the extensions group container (individually per device rather than shared)
- The apps directory is changed from local:

  `[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];`

  to

  `[NSFileManager defaultManager]
  containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.myapp.container"];`

CODE:`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
if (copyDb == YES) {


    NSString *srcPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    NSString *containerPath = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.myapp.container"]path];
    NSString *sqlitePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", containerPath, @"db.sqlite"];


    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:srcPath]) {
        DebugLog(@"Source file doesn't exist locally");
    }

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:sqlitePath]) {
        DebugLog(@"Source file doesn't exist in shared container");
    }
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:sqlitePath]) {
        DebugLog(@"Copying DB to shared group directory");
        NSError *error = nil;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:sqlitePath error:&error];
        if (error != nil) {
            DebugLog(@"Copy failed %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }


}

if (populateData) {

  //app related code if db exists in shared conatiner

  }



- (NSURL *)applicationGroupDocumentDirectory
{
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.myapp.container"];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean.. "between devices"?? A Shared App Group Container... "is working" only if the both APP are on the same physical device

Comment: Answers that, thanks